# Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) READ_CONTACTS permission allows to read Contact's name when permission is denied

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-contacts

I want to check how new permission model works so in app's settings I disable `Contacts`. Then I go to app and try to read `Contacts` and ... it kinda works:

```
try {
    Uri result = data.getData();
    int contentIdx;
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(result, null, null, null, null);
    contentIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        content = cursor.getInt(contentIdx);
    }

    if(content > 0) {
        contentIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            name = cursor.getString(contentIdx);
        }
        contentIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            content = cursor.getLong(contentIdx);
        }
        cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Phone.NUMBER }, Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(content) }, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //SecurityException
}
```

- I'm able to read Contact's Name
- when I try to read Contact's Number `SecurityException` is thrown

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.HtcContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=20123, uid=10593 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()

Why is that?

Related stuff: [Contact data leakage via pick activities](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77384&q=READ_CONTACTS&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)

Comment: Note that you are not using the ContactsContract from google, as you can see, we see that you're accessing com.android.providers.contacts.HtcContractsProvider, maybe HTC  has an issue with validating permission. My suggestion would be to check an AOSP device and see if the same thing is true. If its not true, then it means its a permission leak issue inside of HTC. If they are the same, it sounds like an AOSP issue with.

Comment: It also reproduces on Nexus.

Answer (score 27):

Android marshmallow have new permissions system.
You need to request permissions at run time, using code such as the following — part of which I have copied in here from
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html —

> ```
> @Override public void onClick(View v) {
>     switch (v.getId()){
>         case R.id.tv_contact:{
>             askForContactPermission();
>             break;
>         }
>     }  }
>
> private void getContact(){
>     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
>     startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT); }
>
>  public void askForContactPermission(){
>     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
>         if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
> != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>             // Should we show an explanation?
>             if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
>                     Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
>                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
>                 builder.setTitle("Contacts access needed");
>                 builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
>                 builder.setMessage("please confirm Contacts access");//TODO put real question
>                 builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
>                     @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
>                     @Override
>                     public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
>                         requestPermissions(
>                                 new String[]
>                                         {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}
>                                 , PERMISSION_REQUEST_CONTACT);
>                     }
>                 });
>                 builder.show();
>                 // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
>                 // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
>                 // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
>
>             } else {
>
>                 // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
>
>                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
>                         new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
>                         PERMISSION_REQUEST_CONTACT);
>
>                 // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
>                 // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
>                 // result of the request.
>             }
>         }else{
>             getContact();
>         }
>     }
>     else{
>         getContact();
>     } }
>
> @Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
>                                        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
>     switch (requestCode) {
>         case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CONTACT: {
>             // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
>             if (grantResults.length > 0
>                     && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>                 getContact();
>                 // permission was granted, yay! Do the
>                 // contacts-related task you need to do.
>
>             } else {
>                 ToastMaster.showMessage(getActivity(),"No permission for contacts");
>                 // permission denied, boo! Disable the
>                 // functionality that depends on this permission.
>             }
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // other 'case' lines to check for other
>         // permissions this app might request
>     } }
> ```

Comment: Is there supposed to be some code added after the `// Show an expanation ...` comment?